# AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread'

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library, imread

I got this error 
`AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread'`
I have installed and import "scipy" and "pillow" already. Why I still got this problem?

Comment: please include  the code you used to import the libraries in your post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.misc.imread` is depreciated in SciPy 1.0.0, and removed in Scipy 1.2.0. The documentation suggests using `imageio.imread` instead.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html